# How do I disable a node in Jenkins UI after it has completed its currently running jobs?

Tags: jenkins

I would like to prevent a Jenkins node from executing any further jobs once it has completed those jobs it is already executing.

How can I go about this?  I have currently be telling Jenkins to prepare for shutdown. This incorrectly stops new job allocation to all nodes.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

There is a **"Mark this node temporarily offline"** button in the top right corner of the node's page:

`http://<server>:<port>/computer/<node>/`

Comment: This worked perfectly. The above answer from kazerm is also useful, but did not suit my only temporary requirement for this behavior.

Comment: Is there Jenkins documentation that clarifies this behavior? It's not clear from the text alone "Mark this node temporarily offline" that it will let current jobs complete.

Comment: No, marking the node offline will abort all jobs running in the node. It will not let the currently running jobs complete.

Answer (score 4):

At the node configuration page, under "Availability" you have an option to take the machine offline when it is idle. see attached picture
[image]

Comment: This does not exactly work.  There is a setting 'Disconnect after limited builds', but as of vsphere plugin version 2.14 it is not functioning.  Alternates to this which will take the node offline immediately after the jobs are finished are to use the [Computer API|https://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/Computer.html#setTemporarilyOffline-boolean-hudson.slaves.OfflineCause-] to set the node temporarily offline and do a shutdown with bat or sh command.  Combined with this answer, it will both take it offline at the end of the job but make it available again to be brought back online.

Answer (score 0):

There is a pipeline script with the computer.setTemporarilyOffline() method that worked for me when I tried to run only one build for each node. Note that the line that checks for the existing nodes require permissions that do not exist for Groovy Sendbox so you need to uncheck this checkbox.

[Groovy Sendbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QOvcY.png)

```
    pipeline {
    agent any
​
    stages {
        stage('Hello') {
            steps {
                echo 'Hello World'
            }
        }
    }
    post { 
        always {
        script { 
            markNodeOffline("Mark node as offline")
        }
        }
    }
}
​
@NonCPS
def markNodeOffline(message) {
    node = getCurrentNode(env.NODE_NAME)
    computer = node.toComputer()
    computer.setTemporarilyOffline(true, new hudson.slaves.OfflineCause.ByCLI("Run only one build for each node"))
    computer.doChangeOfflineCause(message)
    computer = null
    node = null
}
​
@NonCPS
def getCurrentNode(nodeName) {
  for (node in Jenkins.instance.nodes) {
      if (node.getNodeName() == nodeName) {
        echo "Found node for $nodeName"
        return node
    }
  }
  throw new Exception("No node for $nodeName")
}
```